# Add Piechart legend scrollbar

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX piechart with 20+ pieces. I would like to add Scrollbar into the location of the legend. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: don't think so - short of implementing a custom chart. Besides, the usability would be horrible, pie's are not for visualizing too many data sets.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work (perhaps surprisingly...):

```
PieChart chart = new PieChart(pieChartData) {

    {
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(getLegend());
        setLegend(scrollPane);
    }
};
```

You might need to configure the scroll pane to some degree to get the exact behavior you want.